# How to Show Dask Dashboard Link When Submitting Dask-Yarn Job Remotely?

Tags: python, dask, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, dask-distributed

**Problem**

Would anyone happen to know how to retrieve the dask dashboard link when I submit my dask-yarn job? I have a print statement for displaying the dask dashboard link, but it doesn't show up in the console. I've also tried logging to stdout and trying to see if it appears in the yarn logs, but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code Example:**

*submit.sh*

```sh
dask-yarn submit \
  --name uq_component_batch_inference \
  --deploy-mode remote \
  --environment uq_component_dask.tar.gz \
  --worker-count 500 \
  --worker-vcores 1 \
  --worker-memory 8GiB \
  --worker-env TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=True \
  --worker-restarts 9 \
  main.py
```

*main.py*

```py
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
cluster = YarnCluster.from_current()
client = Client(cluster)
logging.debug(f"dashboard link: {client.dashboard_link}")
run()
```

**What I've tried:**

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1637895115092_0039 > temp-file.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to explicitly write the scheduler information into a file:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
client.write_scheduler_file("scheduler.json")
```

Note that this doesn't include an explicit link, but the relevant port is in `services -> dashboard`.

Another option is to write the output of `client.dashboard_link` into a file (versus logging as in the snippet you provided).

Comment: I am trying to submit this job using `dask-yarn submit` on deploy `remote` mode but it keeps failing. Seems to work on `local` mode though. I've been trying to debug this all day. Any insight on this?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Among other things, could be access permissions or port forwarding...

Comment: I pretty much followed the example here https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/submit.html. I cannot even find the error in the yarn application logs. It's not really descriptive enough.